# how to assign negative numbers as binary to int variable in java?

Tags: java, binary

I was seeing how to represent binary numbers in java.
one option is to use as `String` and use `Integer.parseInt()` to get the `decimal` value;

The other option (assignment of 2 to `b`):

```
int b = 0b0010; //2
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-2));
```

output:

```
2
11111111111111111111111111111110
```

using this format, how to represent -2:

```
int c=??//-b
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) arithmetic?

Comment: @vandale: I am very familiar with two's complement. I am interested in the representation, not on how to calculate negative binary numbers

Comment: 2's complement relies on a fixed word size, so it would have to be implied then that the value is, say 32 bit long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Bitwise NOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT) operator:

```
00000000000000000000000000000010 // 2 = 0b0010
00000000000000000000000000000001 // 1 = 0b0010-0b0001
11111111111111111111111111111110 // ~1 = ~(0b0010-0b0001)

11111111111111111111111111111110 // -2 = ~(0b0010-0b0001)
```

So you just subtract `0b001` and flip all the bits with the `~` Bitwise operator:

```
int b = ~(0b0010-0b0001); // ~(2-1) = ~1 = -2
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(b));
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/uMplS3)

Answer (score 5):

`int` values are stored in 32 bits where the most significant bit is the sign.

```
0b0010; //2
```

is actually

```
0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000010; //2
```

To convert that to a negative number, you flip the `0`s to `1`s and the `1`s to `0`s` and add 1. So

```
0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000010; //2
0b11111111_11111111_11111111_11111101
0b11111111_11111111_11111111_11111110; // +1
```

And so

```
int b = 0b11111111_11111111_11111111_11111110;
```

would have the value `-2`.

Comment: oh, to represent negative numbers, I need to type in all 32 bits, whereas for positive numbers such as 2, `0b0010` is sufficient..

Comment: @eagertoLearn Right, since its the first bit that decides the sign, you need to put all the bits between that and the value you are trying to represent.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry but i don't think your right. check my answer!

Comment: @rullof We're talking about two different things. If you want to use an integer literal to represent `-2` in binary, you need to specify all the bits. An alternative way to get `-2` is to use the `~` operator as you are suggesting. Another alternative is to just write `-2`. Another alternative is to write `0 - 2`. Ad nauseam.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ok that's right it depends on the point of view

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing storage with presentation. `int b` has no base, regardless of whether you assign `2`, `0b010` or `0x02` to it. Base 10 is just something `println` assumes.

You can use `Integer.toString(number, radix)` to print properly signed binary numbers.